# The method 'copy' isn't defined for the type 'XFile'

Tags: flutter, image, dart, path

I'm getting **The method 'copy' isn't defined for the type 'XFile' error when I try to copy my image to a specific location.**  error. When I try to copy an imaged to a specific location in the device

Detailed error : The method 'copy' isn't defined for the type 'XFile'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'copy'.dartundefined_method

import 'dart:io';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as syspaths;

class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  File _storedImage;

  Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final imageFile = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );
    setState(() {
      _storedImage = File(imageFile.path);
    });
    final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);
    final savedImage = await imageFile.copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  File?  storedImage;

  Future<void>  takePicture() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final imageFile = await picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );
    setState(() {
       storedImage = File(imageFile!.path);
    });
    final appDir = await syspaths.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final fileName = path.basename(imageFile!.path);
    final savedImage = await  File(imageFile.path).copy('${appDir.path}/$fileName');
  }
```

Comment: Glad to help you out enjoy your ride with **Flutter**